# How can I restore Hot Code Replace Failed alert window in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, hotdeploy

### Hot Code Replace Failed window/message was disabled in Eclipse. Now I need reenable it again, how can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have your "Build Automatically" enabled/ticked in eclipse for eclipse to be able to hot swap the code.

Click on Project-->Check "Build Automatically". Start a debugging session and saved changes will be hot swaped.

To be able to see those warnings go to Debug settings(In preferences go to Debug settings) in eclipse and you will see "Hot Code Replace" options to enable/disable warnings shown to the user.